# Total the value of customer orders 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am not able to use the SUM command. The code is on the right path, but, I need it to show the result of the sum of the `ValorPedido` (OrderPrice) in just one row.

```
  SELECT Cliente.CdCliente
        , Cliente.Nome
        , ValorPedido

FROM Cliente

INNER JOIN Pedido ON Cliente.CdCliente = Pedido.CdCliente

WHERE (Cliente.CdCliente = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For one single row you can use `SUM()` with `GROUP BY` clause only :

```
SELECT c.CdCliente, c.Nome, SUM(p.ValorPedido) AS Sums
FROM Cliente c INNER JOIN 
     Pedido p 
     ON c.CdCliente = p.CdCliente
WHERE c.CdCliente = 1
GROUP BY c.CdCliente, c.Nome
```

Note : Use *table* alise that would be easier read and write.

Comment: Hi. TnkYou! But I did on lucky... Yet, ur code is amazing! Here: `select Cliente.cdcliente, cliente.Nome, sum(valorpedido) as ValorPedido from pedido, cliente where pedido.cdcliente = 1 and cliente.cdcliente = 1 group by cliente.cdcliente, cliente.nome`

Answer (score 0):

When using the SUM command you should either select only 1 field or make use of a 
group by statement

```
SELECT SUM(ValorPedido) FROM Cliente 
INNER JOIN Pedido ON Cliente.CdCliente = Pedido.CdCliente
WHERE (Cliente.CdCliente = 1)
```

or option 2

```
SELECT SUM(ValorPedido), Cliente.CdCliente, Cliente.Nome FROM Cliente 
INNER JOIN Pedido ON Cliente.CdCliente = Pedido.CdCliente
WHERE (Cliente.CdCliente = 1)
Group by Cliente.CdCliente, Cliente.Nome
```

I hope that helps

Comment: Thank you! But I did on lucky... Yet, ur code is amazing! Here:

`select Cliente.cdcliente, cliente.Nome, sum(valorpedido) as ValorPedido 
from pedido, cliente
where pedido.cdcliente = 1 and cliente.cdcliente = 1
group by cliente.cdcliente, cliente.nome
`